# Get the date and time app was opened using SharedPreferences in Android Studio

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating an android application using Android Studio.

I need to write a code that saves in a properties file the date and time when the user(for example myself) opened the app. 
So anytime the user(me) opens the app, to write that date and time in that properties file.

I guess that this is done using SharedPreferences but I do not find a solution anywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your app's Launcher Activity (such as SplashActivity if there):

```
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String counterKey = "counterKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //doing basic stuff of set layout and all here...

    //Initialize sharedpreferences here
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //call to increment counter here
    updateAppOpenCounter();

    //do remaining stuff here....
}

private void updateAppOpenCounter() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(counterKey, getAppOpenedCount() + 1);
        editor.commit();
}

private int getAppOpenedCount() {
    sharedpreferences.getInt(counterKey, 0); //Kept 0 as default opened count if not set to shared yet.
}
```

Comment: This looks quite correct. I think this should be accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date by using either `new Date()` or `Calendar.getInstance()`, and you could then format this to a `String` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Storing the String representation of the date the app was opened can be done easily using the [documentation provided by Google on SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).